# Use 8051, How to transfer the correct signal and check it in putty

Tags: c, putty, 8051

I used the KEIL software to program the AT89C51ED2 chip, and I used the USB port to view the data transfer by PUTTY. But in the PUTTY, I can't get accurate information.

The code looks fine, the COM port is also set successfully, there was no problem with the connection of the circuit, but there has a problem in the display of putty.

In the PUTTY, according to ASCII. enter a should get b. but in here a got q, b got r, d got t, and GPRMC got w\SM{

is UART have the problem? or the timer? or other......

There are some code and images below here

```
#include<reg51.h>
char uart_data;
/**
 * FUNCTION_PURPOSE: This file set up uart in mode 1 (8 bits uart) with
 * timer 1 in mode 2 (8 bits auto reload timer).
 * FUNCTION_INPUTS: void
 * FUNCTION_OUTPUTS: void
 */
void main (void)
{
PCON=0;
SCON = 0x50; /* uart in mode 1 (8 bit), REN=1 */
TMOD =  0x20 ; /* Timer 1 in mode 2 */
TH1 = 0xFD; /* 9600 Bds at 11.059MHz */
TL1 = TH1; /* 9600 Bds at 11.059MHz */
ES = 1; // Enable serial interrupt
EA = 1; /* Enable global interrupt */
TR1 = 1; /* Timer 1 run */
while(1); /* endless */
}
/**
 * FUNCTION_PURPOSE: serial interrupt, echo received data.
 * FUNCTION_INPUTS: P3.0(RXD) serial input
 * FUNCTION_OUTPUTS: P3.1(TXD) serial output
 */
void serial_IT(void) interrupt 4
{
if (RI == 1)
{ /* if reception occur */
 RI = 0; /* clear reception flag for next reception */
 uart_data = SBUF; /* Read receive data */
 SBUF = uart_data; /* Send back same data on uart*/
}
else TI = 0; /* if emission occur */
} /* clear emission flag for next emission*/
```

[PUTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhJw8.png)

[PUTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLwwR.png)

[PUTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDrZJ.png)

Comment: the end of the `serial_IT()` function is missing,  The `void main( void )`  should be `int main( void )`  because a 'no OS/bare metal' installation will always start with the `startup'  assembly code (which has to be properly located in memory) so the chips' startup code can find it

Comment: Does the code tell the serial I/O that there are 8 bits or 7 bits of data in each byte?  Does the code tell the serial I/O that there are 1 or 2 stop bits?  Does the code tell the serial I/O that there is no control bit?  Can you connect a debugger to the chip, so you can examine the received byte to determine if the error is occurring on recv or xmit

Comment: Why is `putty` using XON/XOFF for flow control?  The posted code is not using XON/XOFF!